# Include Empty Group in GROUP BY (MYSQL QUERY)

Tags: mysql, sql

I wanted to know if I can include empty groups in my select result.

I'm trying with this query:

```
SELECT
lvl.lvl_name as Level,
slvl.sublvl_name as SubLevel,
sta.stat_name as Status,
count(thg.Id_thing) as Thing_Total
from 
tb_things as thg
LEFT JOIN tb_level lvl ON thg.id_lvl=lvl .id_lvl
LEFT JOIN tb_sublevel slvl ON thg.id_slvl=slvl.id_slvl
LEFT JOIN tb_status sta ON thg.id_stat= sta.id_stat
GROUP BY Level, SubLevel, Status
```

And I'm getting this result:

```
LEVEL   SubLevel    Status      Thing_Total
FIRST   FIRST       WAITING     10
FIRST   SECOND      WAITING     5
FIRST   SECOND      COMPLETE    10
SECOND  FIRST       COMPLETE    15
```

I want to include the rows that show me the groups that have empty data (as 0) by counting with `count(thg.Id_thing)`, something like this:

```
Level   SubLevel    Status      Thing_Total
FIRST   FIRST       WAITING     10
FIRST   FIRST       COMPLETE    0
FIRST   SECOND      WAITING     5
FIRST   SECOND      COMPLETE    10
SECOND  FIRST       WAITING     0
SECOND  FIRST       COMPLETE    15
SECOND  SECOND      WAITING     0
SECOND  SECOND      COMPLETE    0
```

tb_things:

> id_lvl, id_slvl and id_stat will never be null because this table is
>   filled by one script.

```
Id_thing thing_name id_lvl id_slvl id_stat
1        Name1      1      1       1   
2        Name2      1      1       2 
3        Name3      2      1       1 
.
.
```

tb_level:

```
id_lvl lvl_name
1      FIRST
2      SECOND
```

tb_sublevel

```
id_slvl sublvl_name 
1       FIRST
2       SECOND
```

tb_status

```
id_stat stat_name 
1       WAITING
2       COMPLETE
```

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: *"I wanted to know if I can include empty groups in my select result."* - What empty groups? All of your columns seem to contain value.

Comment: 0 does not constitute as being empty.

Comment: Please provide the exact data in each table and we can help with the query you need

Comment: I believe you need to have a full set of data in some table which you are missing. Either a look up table or master table so that you can fill in your `empty groups`.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner that's why I want to show "0" if the status of the group is empty, you can see in my "desire result" that I want to show all the status by group even if they have no data by counting with `count(thg.Id_thing)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your grouping fields seem to have no relation to one another other than via the "things" they are associated with, you will need to synthesize all possible groupings; you can then left join the "things" to that superset. Something like this:

```
SELECT lvl.lvl_name as Level, slvl.sublvl_name as SubLevel, sta.stat_name as Status
   , COUNT(thg.Id_thing) as Thing_Total
FROM tb_level lvl
JOIN tb_sublevel slvl
JOIN tb_status sta 
LEFT JOIN tb_things as thg 
   ON thg.id_lvl=lvl .id_lvl 
   AND thg.id_slvl=slvl.id_slvl
   AND thg.id_stat= sta.id_stat
GROUP BY Level, SubLevel, Status
```

However, if there are any "things" without some grouping references (like a thing with id_lvl and id_slvl set, but an id_stat that is null), those things will be omitted from the results.

Comment: Hey! It worked! Thanks a lot!!!! BTW: id_lvl, id_slvl and id_stat from tb_things will never be null because this table is filled manually by one script.

Comment: You should note that this is non-standard syntax and would fail in any database other than MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `cross join` to define the rows.  Then a `left join` and `group by` to get the count:

```
select l.lvl_name as Level, sl.sublvl_name as SubLevel, s.stat_name as Status,
      count(t.Id_thing) as Thing_Total
from tb_level l cross join
     tb_sublevel sl cross join
     tb_status s left join
     tb_things t
     on t.id_lvl = l.id_lvl and t.id_slvl = s.id_slvl and t.id_stat = s.id_stat
group by Level, SubLevel, Status
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked too! But why should I use `cross join` and not `join`.

Comment: `cross` is optional, as is `inner`; their use is mainly to make the intent more obvious. I'd have included it in mine if it didn't slip my my answer, and if it didn't feel like "copying homework" after I'd seen Gordon's answer simul-posted haha; as I generally dislike lone join keywords stylistically speaking.

Comment: Well thanks a lot, you really saved my day. I'm still learning MYSQL and 
when I get better at this, I will start helping others. Have a nice day!

Comment: @MarceloCalleChávez . . . Why should you use `cross join` and not `join`?  Because you are doing a Cartesian product and that is what `cross join` does.  In any other database, using `join` without an `on` clause would generate a syntax error, because the `on` clause is required by the SQL standard and all other databases.  You should stick with standard SQL.